# Which is more efficient mechanism for Object Identification in QTP - Xpath or Ordinal Identifiers?

Tags: qtp, xpath, uft

Which is more efficient mechanism for Object Identification in QTP - Xpath or Ordinal Identifiers ?

Comment: Can you refine your question? Under what circumstances? How do you define efficient?

Comment: What i meant was , which method would be faster and increase the overall performance of automation script. We have lot of dynamically changing web objects (Webedits ,webelements etc) in the AUT and most of the times description properties alone are not enough to identify them uniquely. So we have to go for descriptive programming (with regular expressions ) or Xpath. We also use ordinal identifiers along with some other properties in descriptive programming. I just want to know in such cases which will be the best and faster way of object identification to improve overall performance.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to put that information in. The more explanation you add, the better answer you're going to get and the less likely it is to get closed for being too broad. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First try with the properties Id,Name. If the objects are not having the unique properties then go for XPATH.